# All my links become active when I toggle them

Tags: reactjs

I have looked across the board for answers, I am not seeing what I need at all. I used a constant to change the color on click for my links, but it seems to activate all of them when one is selected, and deactivate all, when it is selected. Please what can I do?

the toggle function

```
const toggle=()=>{
        setColor(!color);
    }
```

the second set which the function affects

```
<div className="blog-list">
            <ul className="top-nav">
                <li><Link to='' className={'link ' + (color ? 'link-change':'')} onClick={() => {setTabIndex(1); toggle()}}>Tourism in Japan</Link></li>
                <li><Link to='' className={'link ' + (color ? 'link-change':'')} onClick={() => {setTabIndex(2); toggle()}}>Life in Japan</Link></li>
                <li><Link to='' className={'link ' + (color ? 'link-change':'')} onClick={() => {setTabIndex(3); toggle()}}>Accomodation</Link></li>
                <li><Link to='' className={'link ' + (color ? 'link-change':'')} onClick={() => {setTabIndex(4); toggle()}}>Transportation</Link></li>
                <li><Link to='' className={'link ' + (color ? 'link-change':'')} onClick={() => {setTabIndex(5); toggle()}}>Tours & Activities</Link></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

when I click one link, it activates all others. I want it to activate independently when clicked. Please this is for functional component in react

Comment: how is setColor implemented?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because all of your components share the same `color` state variable. You should use `tabIndex` to check if a link should have a certain style. You also don't need to toggle color with this approach.

```
...
<li><Link to='' className={'link ' + (tabIndex === 1 ? 'link-change':'')} onClick={() => {setTabIndex(1);}}>Tourism in Japan</Link></li>
<li><Link to='' className={'link ' + (tabIndex === 2 ? 'link-change':'')} onClick={() => {setTabIndex(2);}}>Life in Japan</Link></li>
...
```

Comment: Thank you for this. worked instantly. I have been doing it all wrong. It is soo simple. Thank you!